# invoke Cloud Function on specific paths

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm invoking a function on every request. can I exclude the /test directory from the rewrite?

```
{
   "hosting":{
      "public":"build",
      "ignore":[
         "firebase.json",
         "**/.*",
         "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites":[
         {
            "source":"/**",
            "function":"helloWorld"
         },
         {
            "source":"**",
            "destination":"/index.html"
         }
      ]
   },
   "functions":{
      "predeploy":[
         "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your rules are overlapping in a way that doesn't make sense since you have two `**` routes. The second one (pointing to `index.html`) will never be matched. You can use a negation to do what you're proposing:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {"source": "!{/test/**}", "function": "helloWorld"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I´m confused what would be the right way then? only one rewrite? how can I specify that I want the function to be triggered for `/*` but not `/` and `/test` ?  pure luck but `{ "source": "**", "destination": "/index.html" }`is making the `/` to not invoke the function

Comment: Static content is [higher priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order) than rewrites so `/` matches to the static file `/index.html`. What I gave you above seems like it will work for what you want - `/` will be `/index.html`, `/test/**` will not be rewritten to the function, and everything else will.